# Android FireBase

Tags: android, база-данных, firebase

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно сделать приложение которое использует FireBase в реальном времени. То есть приложение подключается к серверу, смотрит кто из пользователей сейчас то же пользуется приложением(то есть онлайн) и вывод список этих пользователей и некоторые их данные из таблицы. И у меня возник вопрос. Как сделать проверку пользователя на "онлайн" с помощью возможностей этого сервиса(я с ним почти не знаком) и есть ли хорошая документация/статьи на русском о работе с этим сервисом?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте посмотреть официальные примеры андроид приложений для работы с Firebase на [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android)

Answer (score 1):

Все просто:

- создайте бд(они realtime)
- Создайте массив, например online
- Когда юзер использует приложение, заносите его маил(или id, что вы там используете)
  -Другим пользователям просто показываете список из этого массивы, он сам будет обновляться

Answer (score 1):

вам нужно добавить в `db firebase` значение например isonline: "0" при входе в приложение в это значение будет посылаться "1" при выходе "0" и выводит данные уже по этому значению 
[первоисточник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351689/detect-if-firebase-connection-is-lost-regained)

проверка если онлайне или нет

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase('http://INSTANCE.firebaseio.com');
firebaseRef.child('.info/connected').on('value', function(connectedSnap) {
  if (connectedSnap.val() === true) {
    /* we're connected! */
  } else {
    /* we're disconnected! */
  }
});
```

можете добавить сразу в firebaseRef эту строку и вам выводит всех пользователей кто `isonline`

```
.orderByChild("isonline").equalTo("1");
```

добавление в значение `isonline` 1 если пользователь использует приложение используйте код в `onStart`
и аналогичный код  толка будет посылаться в значение 0 в onDestroy

```
    Map<String, Object> db = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    db.put("isonline", "1");

    firebase.child("your_childeren_name").child(my_uid).child("online").updateChildren(db);
```

Answer (score 0):

Поюзай [Firebase Google Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/products/analytics/). 
Не уверен, но возможно в аналитике есть что-то связанное с on-line пользователями.
Если не разберешься или я ошибаюсь, то попробуй использовать [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore/) создав там отдельную папку с индивидуальными номера юзеров, у которых будет одно значение или true или false.

Попробуй так, это то что в голову пришло.
При запуске программы отправляй true

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("UsersIsOnline")             //папка
            .document("rTrtrT565FHh6frt5654")  //id пользователя
            .update("isOnline", true);         //отправляем true значит в сети
}
```

Ну и само собой, когда пользователь выходит из программы, отправляем false

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("UsersIsOnline")         //папка
        .document("rTrtrT565FHh6frt5654")  //id пользователя
        .update("isOnline", false);        //отправляем false значит не в сети
}
```

Результат на картинке ниже:

[image: как это все выглядет в Cloud Firestore]